# MySQL Join and excluding rows with count=0

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following straightforward query which is part of a garbage collection script. The script is supposed to delete unused shopping carts. A cart is unused when it was updated more than 24 hours ago and is not attached to an order or a user.

```
        $query = "SELECT comm_cart.id AS `cart_id`, (" . time() . " - comm_cart.update_date) AS `diff`, COUNT(comm_orders.cart_id) AS `c1`, COUNT(comm_users.cart_id) AS `c2` " .
             "FROM `comm_cart` " . 
             "LEFT JOIN `comm_orders` ON comm_cart.id=comm_orders.cart_id " . 
             "LEFT JOIN `comm_users` ON comm_cart.id=comm_users.cart_id " . 
             "GROUP BY comm_cart.id "; 
             "HAVING `diff`>86400 AND `c1`=0 AND `c2`=0";
```

The query finds too many carts: it also tags the ones that have a c1>0 or c2>0 and I can't figure out why. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are joining along two different dimensions.  The easy fix is to use `distinct`:

```
SELECT comm_cart.id AS `cart_id`, (" . time() . " - comm_cart.update_date) AS `diff`, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT comm_orders.cart_id) AS `c1`, COUNT(DISTINCT comm_users.cart_id) AS `c2` " .
```

The better solution would be to use `not exists` for these two conditions:

```
FROM comm_carts cc
WHERE not exists (select 1 from comm_orders co where cc.id = co.cart_id )
      not exists (select 1 from comm_users cu where cc.id = cu.cart_id )
```

Comment: Wouldn't these subqueries hurt in the speed department?

Comment: @user3775297 not exists checks in MySQL aren't subqueries(although they're written like them), they're index based lookups if the index exists, or scans similar to the one my code would generate if they don't. Either way they're generally more efficient than other ways of doing it because MySQL has special optimisations for it.

Comment: Ok. Cool. Your solution is very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need the group by, an isnull condition in the where would work wonders, of course I suggest using Gordon's suggestion of the not exists, but if you want the minimum change this would be is.

```
SELECT
    comm_cart.id AS `cart_id`,
    (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - comm_cart.update_date) AS `diff`
FROM `comm_cart`
LEFT JOIN `comm_orders`
  ON comm_cart.id=comm_orders.cart_id
LEFT JOIN `comm_users`
  ON comm_cart.id=comm_users.cart_id
WHERE
  comm_orders.cart_id IS NULL
  AND
  comm_users.cart_id IS NULL
```

Oh, and I've used `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` instead of the PHP time function, same effect, but this avoids mixing PHP and SQL.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to get data with c1=0 and c2=0 then you need to write a where condition instead of having before group by,

```
$query = "SELECT comm_cart.id AS `cart_id`, (" . time() . " - comm_cart.update_date) AS   `diff`, COUNT(comm_orders.cart_id) AS `c1`, COUNT(comm_users.cart_id) AS `c2` " .
         "FROM `comm_cart` " . 
         "LEFT JOIN `comm_orders` ON comm_cart.id=comm_orders.cart_id " . 
         "LEFT JOIN `comm_users` ON comm_cart.id=comm_users.cart_id " . 
         " where c1=0 and c2 =0 and diff >86400 GROUP BY comm_cart.id;
```

Comment: You don't have a group by here, and aggregates don't work in the where clause. Please consider fixing these issues.